# Protect Configuration.plist file in iOS App Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, configuration

After exploring the payload of my app on my desktop I have discovered that when I selected to 'show package contents' - an important configuration.plist file and various image files in my app are readable. This has the URL to content that I wish to be sold, and therefore I need to protect this file, hide it or encrypt it.

I have searched around stackoverflow on how to do this but I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: You can encrypt it with CommonCrypto, use AES and keep the key in the Keychain. Hiding will not accomplish much. But do consider to what extent the items are either particularrly valuable to another and to you. Copyright law is a legal means to protecting your assets from use. No matter what you do there are ways to access your app contents when running since the assets must be available to you app at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) to encrypt/decrypt your data. This is a really easy to use and incredibly safe control for iOS and OS X.

### Encrypting:

```
NSData *data = [@"some_string" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                          password:aPassword
                                             error:&error];
```

### Decrypting:

```
NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData
                                withPassword:aPassword
                                       error:&error];
NSString *someString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[decryptedData bytes]];
```

Comment: Thanks Freshking, this has helped a lot!